# Painting in Android

Tags: android, drawing, paint

Hi Everybody,
 Am a fresher working with android.
 I am facing a problem with the painting activity in my application.
 Please check the below LINK for the code which i have used,

http://marakana.com/tutorials/android/2d-graphics-example.html

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Point point : points) {
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
        // Log.d(TAG, "Painting: "+point);
    }
}
```

The above code is drawing circles at the points where I am moving my finger. Please help me to get the paint whereever i touch my finger (just like normal painting application). I have even used the "drawLine" method, but it is drawing a small line wherever i touch with the finger.
Please help me with the modifications required in the code as soon as possible.

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you: a) add the specific code that you don't understand, such as the onDraw and onTouch methods, to your question so that people don't have to go looking for your code; and b) tell us what you've tried and what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description, it sounds as though new points aren't being added to the `points` array in your `onTouch()` method, or perhaps the `points` array is somehow being cleared, recreated, reinitialized, etc. Compare your code carefully to that in the linked article.

Also, please post the code *straight from your editor* rather than linking to the example you're looking at. I added the `onDraw()` method from the article for you just to give other readers some context, but since the author's code allegedly works, and yours apparently doesn't, it's a good guess that there's a difference. Posting *your* code is the only way that anyone here will be able to detect that.